# Problem with "On the Fly Projection" (OTF) in QGIS 3.4 when upgrading from QGIS version 2.8

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, otf

I just switched from QGIS 2.8 to 3.4. On the fly projection does not appear to be working. None of the Google searches I do provide help. Looks like most folks want to turn OTF off, and it sounds like it is supposed to be on, but each time I add a layer it shows up in an unexpected place.

Comment: In (QGIS 3) _Project ~> Properties ~> CRS_ you can define the map canvas CRS. If the canvas has a defined CRS, then it will reproject the layers _on-the-fly_. If _No projection_ is ticked on, then the map canvas has not a defined CRS and the layers will not be reprojected _on-the-fly_.

Comment: @gabriel de luca why not making your comment an answer ?

Comment: @J.R , I am not sure what the question is.

Comment: There is no question here. It's formatted like a bug report, and the vast majority of users will attest that OTF projection works fine.

Answer (score 4):

About the QGIS 2 *On-The-Fly* reprojection, in QGIS 3:

In QGIS 3, in *Project ~> Properties ~> CRS*, you can define the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) for the project map canvas.

- If the canvas has a defined CRS, then QGIS will reproject the layers *on-the-fly* to that CRS before show them on the map.
- If *"No projection"* is ticked on, then the project map canvas has not a defined CRS and the layers will not be reprojected *on-the-fly*. The layers will be shown on the map without reproject them to a common CRS.